# Cant Log Into Wordpress Admin: Nginx Issue - SSL?

Tags: nginx, wordpress, cache

For some reason I get a 301 redirect loop when I force SSL_admin. No big deal I simply click the icon to load unsecure elements but now I cant log into the admin area at all.

I already tried SERVER SSL on ... and a variety of other things

```
              proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
              proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
              proxy_set_header  X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
              proxy_redirect    off;
              proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

         proxy_pass http://IP:8080;
```

I tried this but to no avail:

```
set $no_cache "";

set $cache_uri $request_uri;


    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
 if ($request_uri ~* "(sitemap.xml|sitemap.xml.gz|/wp-admin/|/auth-php|/xmlrpc$

        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
        set $no_cache 1;
    }
```

Comment: What are you proxy passing to?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking whether any headers fit I just pasted this into wp-config.php

> $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';

Also changed

> proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;

to

> proxy_set_header  Host $host;

Comment: Ah, it's you again. For the second time, get rid of Apache. That's where all your problems are coming from.